# how to access the queue in a thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, queue

I create a queue in a thread which will be running all the time. This thread is maintaining this queue and get message from the queue in certain period of time.
My question is how can i access this queue in another class or servlet?? and insert message into this queue. Just make this queue static ??
Do i need to consider multithreading??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a static variable where the other class can access the reference to the queue, or you have to pass a reference to the queue into the other class that needs to access it.

Yes, you have to be careful about multi-threading anytime you access an object from two different threads, although the details of what you need to do will depend upon the specific queue class you are using.